# Media Element will not play a song for the first time, or at all.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a little problem with playing a song selected from a simple ListPickerFlyout, now, this works

```
private async void MusicFilesList_ItemsPicked(ListPickerFlyout sender, ItemsPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            StorageFile selectedMusic = sender.SelectedItem as StorageFile;

            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await selectedMusic.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                this.MusicPlayer.SetSource(stream, selectedMusic.ContentType);
                this.MusicPlayer.Play();
            }

        }
```

It works just fine except for a tiny little bug that really disturbs me- the first time I select a song- it will not play, only from the second time. Now I debugged and  I saw that it actually enters the handler the first time too, but for some reason it only plays the second time. Strange, however I was told that I should write the event handler the following way -

```
  private  void MusicFilesList_ItemsPicked(ListPickerFlyout sender, ItemsPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            StorageFile selectedMusic = sender.SelectedItem as StorageFile;
            this.MusicPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
            this.MusicPlayer.Source = new Uri(selectedMusic.Path);
            this.MusicPlayer.Play();
        }
```

To me - looks just fine, but won't play the song at all. Could someone explain why the first one is not working properly, the second one is not working at all and what actually is a proper way to play music using media element ?

Comment: Apparently , getting rid of the using clause fixes the problem with the first approach not working the first time, however it still remains unclear why the second one does not work at all, I suspect it's a windows phone 8.1 problem since I have read somewhere that it actually works for silverlight, but I would be really glad to read other opinions as well.